# load search results into a div jquery and rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, load

In my rails app I have a search bar where users can search other users. Currently when a User submits the search from, they're redirected to a "results" page. I want to load those results in a div on the same page.. I was able to do this with my websites navigation links, but I'm pretty new to jQuery and rails and can't figure this one out...

my jQuery corresponding to my navigation links:

```
$(function() {
    $('#links a').live('click', function() {
        $('#pages').load(this.href).fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

my attempt to do the same with my search function...

```
$(function() {
  $("input#search").parents("form").submit(function() {
    $('#pages').slideUp('slow').load(this.href).slideDown('slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

any help would be much appreciated~ along with some useful jQuery tutorials for a newbie!!

my form:

```
<div id="search_bar">
  <form action="/search" method="get">
    <input class="tb10" id="search" name="search" onclick="this.select();" type="text" value="Find Users" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try `return false;` in the search function also. returning false cancels the default event from being triggered on the element.

Comment: I just did a test, try to spit out alert('test'), it seems as if jQuery isn't finding my form ID? In my rails app, I specify the form_tag with an :id => "search".. my form (actually just a text field) does not have a submit button... to use .submit do I need one?

Comment: if `#search` identifies a `<input>` tag then `submit()` won't work, you'll need to bind to `click()`. `submit()` only works for `<form>` tags as far as I know,

Comment: sbeam is right. If you want to submit the form of the search you can either change the ID of the form, or use $("input#search").parents("form").submit();

Comment: Thank you Zach, I got the code to respond to alert('hello world');. So I know that Jquery is finding the right element, but the page is still not loading in the div... in actuality, the text field no longer responds, I just see the animations. I've updated the post to reflect what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example your binding the event to an anchor which has an href element that its reading to know where to get your links from.

In the second it looks like you've copied and pasted what worked for your links.  You need to know where you're form is getting processed (the action of your form), and what is being passed to it as the form data. This is done as follows in jquery:(I'm assuming #search is the id of your search form)

```
$(function(){
     $("#search").submit(function(){
         var queryString = $(this).serialize(); //gets the values in your form
         var url = $(this).attr("action"); //your action url
         $("#pages").load(url+"?"+queryString).fadeIn('slow');
         return false; //this prevents your form from doing its default behavior.
     });
});
```

I'm not very familiar with RoR, but the jquery should be solid :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for your response, yeah it was a copy and paste. I figured that rails would do all the background stuff and I can just redirect the html that rails spits out into a div..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able do give you a RoR example here at the moment but I think the answer is all about JQuery.

Basically I see this done with an ajax request to get the search result and show that result with a templating system like jquery Templates or Mustache.

This approach will make it easier for you to generate the html instead of trying to pump a webpage into a div

JQuery Templates: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/
Mustache for Rails: https://github.com/adamsalter/mustache-rails

Comment: hmm ok ill check it out thanks, I was wondering what "template" was